# Как использовать индексаторы в xaml без квадратных скобок?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть некий generic класс

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
    public object this[string s]
    {
        return s;
    }
}
```

Ну и экземпляр класса используется как DataContext. Тогда для вызова из xaml будет такая разметка

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding [qwer]}"/>
```

и вернет она текст "qwer".

Вопрос, а можно ли какими либо ухищрениями избавиться от квадратных скобок? Вот есть класс DataView, как там это реализовано?

Comment: А почему нужно избавиться от квадратных скобок? Это часть какой-то задачи или просто интересно, как сделано в DataView (кстати, никогда не использовал почему-то)?

Comment: Можно избавиться, получиться обычный биндинг на свойство.

Comment: @Monk, только свойства такого нет.

Comment: @VladD, чтобы можно было использовать, например, в элементах, где есть свойство типа `DisplayMemberPath`.

Comment: @iRumba я неправильно выразился - если вы избавитесь от скобок, то это будет синтаксис обычного биндинга.

Comment: Ну, поскольку индексатор по идее не даёт нотификаций об изменениях, то например поможет конвертер: `{Binding Converter={StaticResource IndexingConverter} ConverterParameter=qwer}`. Но этот подход наверное не то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @VladD, но DataView же дает )

Comment: @VladD, я хочу попробовать реализовать ViewModel<T>, в конструктор которой будет передаваться какой нибудь экземплярчик любого типа. В результате планируется, что изменять свойства из кода можно будет  напрямую в этом экземпляре, а к вьюхе привязывать экземпляр класса ViewModel

Comment: @iRumba приведите примеры кода, чтобы было понятно, что вы хотите получить

Comment: @Monk, я привел то что хочу получить. Если не хватает каких то данных, скажите конкретнее каких

Comment: @VladD, короче автоматическая ViewModel )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашел решение. Класс `public class GenericClass<T>` должен наследовать интерфейс `ICustomTypeDescriptor` и индексатор в нем вообще не нужен. Тогда Мне нужно из конструктора просто подбирать передаваемый объект типа `Т` и использовать его как ресурс для реализации интерфейса.

---

Я не выложу дословный код, потому что не имею его под рукой. Могу лишь из памяти набросать его основу

Класс:

```
public class ViewModel<T>: ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    T _source;

    public ViewModel(T obj)
    {
        _source = obj;
    }

    // далее идет реализация интерфейса. Все методы сделаны идентично, я приведу пример одного
    public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(_source);
    }
}
```

Класс еще не готов. Нужно еще наследовать INotifyPropertyChanged и предусмотреть мониторинг свойств модели или иные способы изменения свойств из кода. Но это совсем другая история )

Comment: Кодец бы добавили.

Comment: Отличное решение! Поддерживаю предыдущего оратора — вашему ответу не хватает примера с кодом.